# How to set scrollable and non-scrollable cloumns of a dynamic React Table

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a React Table where starting 3 columns of the table should be fixed, and the rest should be scrollable. Normally I would have written a css like:

```
 {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0px;>width from left where I want it to be sticked, this 
    can be 0, 100 etc which is 
    addition of the width of previous columns
    z-index: 1;
    }
    {
    position: sticky;
    left: 100px;>width from left where I want it to be sticked, 
    this can be 0, 100 etc which is 
    addition of the width of previous columns
    z-index: 1;
    }
    {
    position: sticky;
    left: 200px;>width from left where I want it to be sticked, 
    this can be 0, 100 etc which is 
    addition of the width of previous columns
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

The issue I have right now is the Table is also dynamic - we can reorder the columns. And each column has different width. I can get  the exact width in the tsx file where I can assign it to const. but how do I import that const from .tsx file to .less file? In end how do I make left property dynamic.

Comment: Please format your code correctly and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).